# ASP.NET BoilerPlate: .Net core template - app service error

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am in the process of moving my app code **from** the **.Net5 MVC/JQuery ASPNETZERO template** to the new **.Net core 1.1 MVC/JQuery template**.
So far I have copied over my first few custom entities. Created a EF migration and applied the changes to my DB. 
I then started building the first app service for one of my entities. I am copying over the code from my existing MVC template that is working without any issues.

```
      public async Task<PagedResultDto<ListValuesListDto>> GetListValues(GetListValuesInput input)
    {
        var query = from lv in _listvaluesRepository2.GetAll()
                    select new ListValuesListDto
                    {
                        Id = lv.Id,
                         ListName = lv.ListName,
                         ListText = lv.ListText
                    };
        query = query.WhereIf(!input.Filter.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(), lv => lv.ListName.Contains(input.Filter) || lv.ListText.Contains(input.Filter));
        var resultCount = await query.CountAsync();
        var results = await query.OrderBy(input.Sorting).PageBy(input).ToListAsync();
        return new PagedResultDto<ListValuesListDto>(resultCount, results);
    }
```

The method above is from my MVC template. When I place this into the .Net core solution, I keep getting the following build error.

> CS0411    The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.OrderBy(IEnumerable, Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

The error is pointing to the "OrderBy" on this line of code:

```
      var results = await query.OrderBy(input.Sorting).PageBy(input).ToListAsync();
```

I am still very much learning the ABP template and EF. I cannot for the life of me figure out why the same code in the .Net core template does not work?

Any help that anyone can provide would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just solved my own issue. I had to add the using statement for `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`

Hope it helps someone else! :-)